# Updating private field with Firebase Cloud: best practice for security

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firestore with some private documents (no write). My rules are already setup for this. For example, a document could contain the credits or subscription tier for a user. I want to let the backend update these fields instead of the client, for obvious reasons. However, I was wondering, if I create a generic updatePrivateField method in Cloud functions, would it be considered best practice?

```
exports.updateProtectedField = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "Authentication Required"
    );
  }

  const { collection, id, update } = data;
  try {
    await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection(collection)
      .doc(id)
      .update({
        ...update,
      });
    return { msg: "Update successful", code: 200 };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", error.message, error);
  }
});
```

Basically, what I am wondering is, is creating an endpoint like this considered safe? I am checking if the user is authenticated, but couldn't they just POST to the endpoint with their own login credentials and update any field in the database?

Thanks, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

### In case of a user can update own document.

Should set context.auth.uid as document id.

```
exports.updateProtectedField = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Check context.auth.uid
  if (!context.auth || !context.auth.uid) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "Authentication Required"
    );
  }

  const { collection, update } = data;
  // Set context.auth.uid as document id
  try {
    await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection(collection)
      .doc(context.auth.uid)
      .update({
        ...update,
      });
    return { msg: "Update successful", code: 200 };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", error.message, error);
  }
});
```

### In case of a some role (ex. admin) can update a user document.

Should use Custom Claims and check it.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

ex. Use a admin role

```
// Add any trigger or any condition you want.

// Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.

admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

```
exports.updateProtectedField = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Check user is admin
  if (!context.auth || !context.auth.token.admin) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "Authentication Required"
    );
  }

  const { collection, id, update } = data;
  try {
    await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection(collection)
      .doc(id)
      .update({
        ...update,
      });
    return { msg: "Update successful", code: 200 };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", error.message, error);
  }
```

More documents

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext#auth
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/functions-and-firebase
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk
- https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase

Comment: Thanks for the reply zkohi! So to understand how security works in the backend : in the first method, if I am logged in as a user, couldn't I just make a POST request with my credentials to that API endpoint and update my credits or change my subscription tier? Or let's say I have another scenario where an action from the client has to change a document with no write access that is different from the client making the call. Like client A needs to make changed to client B document. How would I securely implement this on the backend without giving special permissions to a user?

Comment: `Protocol specification for https.onCall` is  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference . A someone who knew token can make a POST request with token and update credits or change subscription tier. If the token is not valid, the request is rejected. `Secure data access for users and groups` document is https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access . I think It is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cloud Functions code allows any authenticated user to update any document. It is pretty much the equivalent of these security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection/{document=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If that is what you want to accomplish, I recommend doing so with the above security rules as it'll be both simpler and cheaper than introducing Cloud Functions to the mix.

---

If a user should only be able to update their own document through this (as zhoki's answer suggests by using `context.auth.uid`), then that'd be the equivalent of these security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection}/{userId} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

If this is the use-case you're looking for, I'd again recommend using security rules to secure it and bypass Cloud Functions for a simpler and cheaper solution.

---

In both of the cases above the `{collection}` allows the user to update documents in any collection, since that is what your Cloud Functions code also seems to do. It is much more common to limit the update to a specific collection, in which case you'd replace `{collection}` with just that collection name.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I understand how my current function is not secure. My app is basically a teacher/student matchup platform. What I would specifically like to do is : 
1. A teacher creates a class.
2. A student sends a request to join the class
3. Teacher accepts the request. Student ID is added to participants array in the class document.

What I don't want to happen, is to have a malicious teacher potentially fill the participants array with some student IDs, even though they never applied. How would I go around solving that?